# calculating the area of 3D NURBS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, area, spline

for a given 3D NURBS, for example the roof below:

[architectural use of NURBS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMODO.jpg)

how can the area of 3D NURBS be calculated?